# retrieve data from the database, use the data as an argument for a java method

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My objective is to retrieve data from the database using SQL command then use the data retrieved from the cell as an argument for a method and save the result of the function in the database.

for example:

```
id  column1  column2  result
1   5        9        --
2   22       40       --
```

what i want is a command to retrieve the data from column1 and column2 with SQL query then use them as arguments for the a method ( example: minus(column2,column1) //which calculâtes the difference between the data of the 2 columns) then save the result in the column called result. And then do this for all the columns of the database.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: well actually i am a beginner, i only analyzed what i have to do, but i don't know where to start or is it posible to be done.

Comment: yes its possible, but you need to first learn how to deal with databases through java. and for minus() method you need to put your  logic

Comment: is there a certain topic to focus on for this problem ??

Comment: something like  "select column1+column2 as result  from tablename"

Comment: in your case there is two operation, so first read about JDBC http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

then read about method how to call methods in java

Comment: @Rishi he dont know anything about coding

Comment: ok thanks khan & rishi, i'll work on those and return back here if i upfronted a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a small example, although you should have a good read at JDBC adn specifically at [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

```
//create an SQL statement first..
statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_name=?");

//obtain the result set...
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

// here you obtain an array from the resultset, but you can fetch many other data types 
String[] arrayResult = resultSet.getArray(String columnLabel);

// and then you can pass an element of that array (say the first element) as an argument to a method
myClass.myMethod(arrayResult[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks Anto for the help.